# What decides which kernel modules are built in the kernel statically during compilation?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

I just compiled a new kernel and asked myself: What decides during the compilation process which kernel modules are built in the kernel statically?

I then deleted `/lib/modules`, rebooted and found that my system works fine, so it appears all essential modules are statically built in the kernel.

Without `/lib/modules`, the kernel loads 22. With the directory present, it loads 67 modules.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do this as part of the configuration process, usually when you run `make config`, `make menuconfig` or similar. You can set the module as built-in (marked as `*`), or modularised (marked as `M`).

You can see examples of this in a screenshot of `make menuconfig`, from [here](http://linuxgazette.net/125/misc/pfeiffer/kernel_ipsec1.png):

[image: menuconfig screenshot]

Comment: In which source file do I find the default settings in case I don't change anything?

Comment: .config in the folder where You issued make && make menu_config.

Comment: What I meant was, how are the default settings retrieved? There is no .config when I download the kernel sources, it gets generated when I adopt the default settings after executing `make config`. But I wanted to know where does `make config` take the default settings from?

Comment: Or let's put it this way: where does `make defconfig` take its default values? Based on [this link](http://www.linux.org/threads/the-linux-kernel-configuring-the-kernel-part-1.4274/) it `creates a config file that uses default settings based on the current system's architecture`. But how does it get the `current system's architecture`?

Comment: @JohnnyFromBF They're set in the `Kconfig` for the architecture in the kernel sources, for example, see the "default" lines in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/Kconfig

Answer (score 4):

Given that you added the tag `/kernel` in addition to `/linux-kernel`, I assume that you are interested in the generic case as well.

In Solaris since 1991, everything is dynamically loaded, except the basic kernel glue code, the default scheduler and the pager/swapper.

Even the root filesystem code and the module loader is dynamically loaded.

This avoids the need to manually configure the kernel. Given that Solaris does not need to configure size dependent features as well (new kernel objects are automatically created at run-time as long as there is enough memory) there is no need for any manually configuration on Solaris.

I am wondering when Linux will reach this state of automation...
I however believe that this will never happen as the theorectically unneeded kernel configuration (see Solaris) is used as a funny method to tell users `hey, you are able to control the linux kernel`.

Comment: Linux is also dynamically loaded. However unlike the scenario you describe for Solaris (I don't know Solaris well so you may be misdescribing things) you, the user, have the option to statically compile device drivers directly into the kernel. This makes Linux significantly more useful compared to Solaris for use in embedded devices etc.

Comment: Note the screenshot in the answer by Chris. When compiling the kernel you get to choose to either dynamically load a module (the `<M> Modularize` option) or statically compile it in (the `<Y> Includes` option)

Comment: Doing it "the Linux way" also allows you to fully disable loadable kernel modules, which in some scenarios and given certain threat models can increase security (by ensuring that there is no readily available way to inject executable code into a running kernel). *Loadable kernel module support* is one option among many in the Linux kernel configuration. (And you can compile almost everything in the Linux kernel as loadable modules too, if that's your cup of tea.)

Comment: Solaris implements signed kernel modules for security.

Comment: So does Solaris use an initial RAM disk or something like it? How can modules be loaded without a module loader?